RVIZ GUI - problem using signal/slot mechanism
I want to create an rviz panel. Using a demo code from chatgpt, a previous code i once used and this tutorial, i made a very simple panel, but it could not load at all. Initially, i tried using the signal and slot mechanisms, which i had used previosuly. When i removed the QSLOT and Q_OBJECT macros, i finally managed to add the panel in rviz, and it worked successfully.
Also, now, i do not have to have this:
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

My question is: Is this approach viable and "correct", or am i missing something? Do you have any idea why it did not work in the first place. I spend a lot of time debugging it, and i would like to know what i am missing.

In the same computer i had previously worked on a gui in rviz with the signal/slot mechanisms. I have not changed the rviz/ros installation.
I am using: rviz_QT_VERSION: 5.12.8

Code:
header:
namespace arm_ui {

class armPanel : public rviz::Panel  {
    
    Q_OBJECT // this is removed to work
    public:
      armPanel(QWidget* parent = 0);

    private Q_SLOTS: // Q_SLOTS is removed to work
      void onButtonClicked(); 

    private:
      QPushButton* button_;
    };
}

source:
namespace arm_ui{
  armPanel::armPanel(QWidget* parent)
    : rviz::Panel(parent)
  {
    QVBoxLayout* layout  = new QVBoxLayout;
    button_ = new QPushButton("Click Me");
    layout->addWidget(button_);
    setLayout(layout);

    connect(button_, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onButtonClicked()));
  }

  void armPanel::onButtonClicked()
  {
    ROS_INFO("Button clicked!");
  }
}

#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(arm_ui::armPanel, rviz::Panel)

To make it work, i changed the slot mechanism with this:
    connect(button_, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &armPanel::onButtonClicked);

